# iOS static image load in webview

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I want to show a local image from CachesDirectory in a webview.
The webview can't load it. The bundle doesn't contain the image!

I download the image from the server but I have a local HTML file with the image tag. How can I do it?

My path where the image exists:

> /Users/adambella/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BFA8C179-EBC5-49A7-95F3-1ABA202F44AD/data/Containers/Data/Application/746BE86B-33D7-4A6F-8C4C-0E4453FE374C/Library/Caches/swift.imageloader.diskcached/

Anybody could give me a short example?

**I downloaded it with ImageLoader.
Path with Name:**

```
var path: String {
    let cacheDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.CachesDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    let directoryName = "swift.imageloader.diskcached"

    return cacheDirectory + "/" + directoryName
}

let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("example", ofType: "html",inDirectory: "Directory")

let urlToFile = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)

let request = NSURLRequest(URL: urlToFile, cachePolicy: .ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
```

**and in webViewDidFinishLoad method:**

```
webview2.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("testImage('\(path)')")
```

**function in html file:**

```
function testImage(url) {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map");
    mapDiv.innerHTML = "<img src=file://" + url + "/>";
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that you have tried ?

Comment: Yes, I have just edited the description

Answer (score 0):

This is Swift 4.2 code.

base URL in you can set Image URL

```
web.loadRequest(URLRequest.init(url: baseURL!))
```

If you have any query please comment